# Solving an ODE: closed forms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I am given the following system.

\begin{split}
\overset{.}{x}&= y\\
\overset{.}{y}&= k(1-y^2)^{3/2}e^{-x}
\end{split}

writing $dx= \overset{.}{x}dt$ and $dy= \overset{.}{y}dt$ we arrive at

$$\frac{ydy}{(1-y^2)^{3/2}}= ke^{-x}dx$$

Integrating both sides yields

$$(1-y^2)^{-1/2}= ke^{-x}+c.$$

How do I get close forms of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in terme of $t$?

Comment: Just an integral form? Or closed form in terms of "nice functions"?

Comment: @CalvinKhor A closed form if any please.

Answer (score 2):

> $(1-y^2)^{-1/2} -c = ke^{-x}$

So,

$\frac{dy}{dt} = k(1-y^2)^{3/2}e^{-x} = (1-y^2)^{3/2}((1-y^2)^{-1/2} -c)$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = 1-y^2  -c(1-y^2)^{3/2} =(1-y^2)(1-c(1-y^2)^{-1/2})  $

> If the constant $c$ were zero, it'd become much simpler

$\frac{dy}{dt} = 1-y^2 $

$\int\frac{1}{1-y^2}dy = \int dt$

$\frac{1}{2}\ln\bigg\vert\frac{y+1}{y-1}\bigg\vert = t+c'$

$\frac{y+1}{y-1} = e^{2t+2c'} = \alpha e^{2t}$ , $\alpha = e^{2c'}$

> $$y = \frac{\alpha e^{2t}+1}{\alpha e^{2t}-1}$$

Now, $\frac{dx}{dt} = y = \frac{\alpha e^{2t}+1}{\alpha e^{2t}-1}$

$\int dx = \int \frac{\alpha e^{2t}+1}{\alpha e^{2t}-1}dt$

On integrating,

> $$x = \ln|\alpha e^{2t} -1| - t + \beta$$

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\frac{\ddot x}{(1-\dot x^2)^{3/2}}=ke^{-x}$$

which integrates as

$$(1-\dot x^2)^{-1/2}=c-ke^{-x}.$$

From this we draw a separable but nasty equation

$$\dot x=\sqrt{1-\frac1{(c-ke^{-x})^2}}.$$

Anyway, this gives us the trajectory $y$ in terms of $x$.